В шаблонах blade laravel для указания путей используется asset(), есть ли что-то подобное в компонентах vue 3?
Пример
<script src="{{ asset('js/script.js') }}"></script>


Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Думаю вам надо обратить внимание на Vite

Альтернатива в vue-компонентах может быть такой:
<script src="@/js/script.js"></script>

Есть еще такой вариант, только нужно полный путь указывать
<script :src="`js/script.js`"></script>

